# Yii Active Record COALESCE not displaying result

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, coalesce

I have the following query:

```
$result = Table1::model()->findAll(array(
    'with' => array(
                'table2' => array(
                    'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN',
                    'on' => 'pk = fk AND fk=1'
                )
            ),
    'select' => array('name',
                      'COALESCE(table2.price, t.standardprice) AS price',
                      'COALESCE(table2.period, t.period) AS period')
    )
);
```

My goal is to pick table2's fields if those are filled in, but if these are empty / no rows found the original table's fields should be displayed.

However, my output isn't as expected. The `price` field isn't displayed at all in my result's attributes, and the `period` field is either table2's value or empty.

EDIT: Perhaps my SQL is wrong somewhere. Using this SQL gives me the wanted results:

```
SELECT name, COALESCE(tb1.price, tb2.standardprice) as price, COALESCE(tb1.period, tb2.period) as period
FROM table1 as tb1
LEFT JOIN table2 as tb2
ON (tb1.pk= tb2.fk) AND fk=1;
```

Yet I don't see any difference with my current code.

EDIT2: Table structures:

**Table1** (original table)

```
pk            (int 11) - Primary key, auto increment
name          (varchar 255)
standardprice (decimal 11,2)
period        (varchar 255)
fkLanguage    //not relevant
photo         //not relevant
description   //not relevant
link          //not relevant
```

**Table2**

```
ID      (int 11) - Primary key, auto increment
fk      (int 11) - Foreign key, which links to pk of table1
period  (varchar 255)
price   (decimal 11,2)
fkType  //not relevant
amount  //not relevant
```

**Clarification**: The `fk=1` *is* indeed a JOIN condition. If the fk isn't 1 then I don't want those rows to join, but take the values from table1 instead.

Comment: why do you add this: AND fk=1 ??

Comment: @AladdinHoms I only need to select certain rows by ID from the second table, not all of them. Later on this will become a parameter such as `fk=:id`

Comment: Do you have properties `price` and `period` in table of model Tablename? Can you show it structure?

Comment: @CreatoR added table structures to first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add column `price` for parsing not existing column in schema.
Try to modify model Table1 ()

- add `public $price;`
- override method attributeNames to following:

> ```
> public function attributeNames()
>   {
>       $colums = parent::attributeNames();
>       $colums[] = 'price';
>       return $colums;
>   }
> ```

Comment: Could we make a private chat? I don't really understand how your solution would work or where to add this function.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how, I'm here less than 2 weeks... I'm waiting your request

Comment: Haha I was hoping you knew. Well I guess we can use this empty room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37891/php-for-noobs

Comment: Solved through chat: renaming my "standardprice" column in table1 to "price" did the trick. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this:

```
$result = Tablename::model()->findAll(array(
'with' => array(
            'tabel2' => array(
                'joinType' => 'LEFT JOIN',
                'on' => 'pk = fk'
            )
        ),
'select' => array('name',
                  'COALESCE(tabel2.price, t.standardprice) AS price',
                  'COALESCE(tabel2.period, t.period) AS period'),
'condition'=> ' fk = 1 '
));
```

because fk = 1 is not a part of the on statement; it is only a condition. I think that will make the difference for you.

Comment: This doesn't work, even though it would seem logical. This returns only the rows where table2 has a matching `fk`. What I need is ALL rows, and if table2 has no matching keys, it fills in the "default" values which are given in table1.